# Best way to introduce a new 2008R2 Domain Controller into a Domain to replace an existing 2003 DC

Tags: domain, directory, controller

This should be an easy one for some of you guys with DC and AD experience.

I am introducing a new DC running 2008R2 to replace a DC I have running 2003. I have run through all the set up and I have the new 2008R2 (DC-04)  running alongside the existing 2003 domain controller (DC-03), I also have another 2003 DC (DC-02) which I am leaving alone.

Since I have this DC-04 up and running with 2008R2, I was planning on shutting down DC-03, and renaming DC-04 to DC-03 so it replaces it. After some research it seems this may cause some issues since the DC-03 name already exists in my system.

What is the best course of action here, is there a good way to clear out all references to DC-03 and then rename DC-04 to DC-03?

Or is it better to just demote DC-03, shut it down, and leave DC-04 with the name it has now? Will computers in my domain know to look to DC-04?

Any help is greatly appreciated,
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just create your new DC and demote the old one.

You can do either, if you're really set on having a DC with the old name, [you can rename a DC, but it's more of a pain than it's worth](http://www.petri.co.il/rename-windows-server-2008-domain-controllers.htm), in my opinion.  Ask yourself what function keeping the old name serves and if it's really worth the effort.  In my experience, it's not.

(Oh, and since I forgot to mention it, makes sure the removal of the old DC has finished propagating through AD before you rename the new DC, if you go that route.)